# Magento2 How to get customer billing agreement by entity_id

Tags: customer, customer-account, billing-agreements

How to get customer billing agreement data. I can't find a table in the database. can someone guide me to get data or query?

Answer (score 1):

You can access it from this method :

```
/**
 * Retrieve billing agreements collection
 *
 * @return \Magento\Paypal\Model\ResourceModel\Billing\Agreement\Collection
 */
public function getBillingAgreements()
{
    if ($this->_billingAgreements === null) {
        $this->_billingAgreements = $this->_agreementCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()
        )->setOrder(
            'agreement_id',
            'desc'
        );
    }
    return $this->_billingAgreements;
}
```

Defined here: `vendor\magento\module-paypal\Block\Billing\Agreements.php`

Comment: Do you know where the database been stored? I can't find anything in the database this using a collection right so this has to be stored in somewhere but not sure where exactly.

Comment: you can find it here - `paypal_billing_agreement` and you can find the relevant orders here -  `paypal_billing_agreement_order`

Comment: thank you @arif